# Angular Display NG-Repeat Display

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

I have the following code to display 3 different types on the page:

1. Production
2. Development
3. Maintenance

And I want the entire section (Production h4 and table/tbody) to disappear if there is no content in filteredResults. (Only appear if there is content)

```
    <span ng-repeat="type in types">
      <table class="max-width">
        <tbody>
          <div class="row" ng-repeat="result in filteredResults = (results | filter:search) | filter: status('status', type)">
            <div class="left-header-padding" ng-if="$index==0">
              <tr class="pull-left">
                <h4 class="title">{{type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.substring(1)}}</h4>
              </tr>
            </div>
          </div>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </span>
```

I am currently trying ng-if for content inside the table, checking if ng-repeat occurs and only rendering the  if there is content in ng-repeat, but I want the entire section (table included) to disappear when there is no content. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

if you want hide table put ng-show into table tag ie:

```
<table class="max-width" ng-show="filteredResults.length >0">
    <tbody>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="result in filteredResults = (results | filter:search) | filter: status('status', type)">
            <div class="left-header-padding">
                <tr class="pull-left">
                     <h4 class="title">{{type}}</h4>

                </tr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: In your example, can the table know what filteredResults is if its a calcualted/filtered list inside the table?? Isn't it out of scope when it checks for the length??

Comment: @KrishnaTejaVeeramachaneni are you sure ? see demo of Jossef

Comment: Yup. Seems like it works that way too. Good to know. Seems like the filteredResults is added to the scope and so it can be used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

add `ng-show="filteredResults.length"` to your `table` element

```
<table ... ng-show="filteredResults.length">
```

### example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WFQzRtXFe3UnvuzA8psa?p=preview

**also**, iv'e used `tr` inside `tbody` instead of `div`

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-init to create a local filtered collection and use the ng-if statement to hide the table if there is no items in the filtered collection.

```
   <div ng-repeat="type in types">
     <div ng-init="filteredResults = (results | filter:search) | filter: status('status', type)">
         <table class="max-width" ng-if="filteredResults.lenght > 0">
            <tbody>
              <div class="row" ng-repeat="result in >
                <div class="left-header-padding" ng-if="$index==0">
                  <tr class="pull-left">
                    <h4 class="title">{{type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.substring(1)}}</h4>
                  </tr>
                </div>
              </div>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Let me know if you have any questions.